# Magento admin order PayPal email link module

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, paypal

I am looking for a way to create an admin order in Magento that, once submitted, sends an email containing a link to pay by PayPal with the payment linked to the order so that the status updates automatically from pending to processing once the payment has been received.

Is this possible - has anyone else either found a module to do this or had a custom module built.

I have just switched to Magento from OpenCart and my admin order section in OpenCart had this functionality so my customers and staff expect to be able to use it in Magento.  It is particularly important when conversing with customers over Facebook as they often ask to pay by PayPal and request us to build the order for them.  I can build the order in Magento but can't see any easy way to send them a link requesting payment...

Help please!!!

Thanks,

Hugh

Comment: You can already keep customers up to date with Magento.